# Java -ea path of a (sub)package

Tags: java, package, assert

If I have the following packages:

```
com.foo
com.foo.one
com.foolish
```

each containing classes. Then will the command below enable assertions on the com.foolish package?

```
java -ea:com.foo...
```

It's weird because I'm reading a book which mention sub-packages here with -enableassertions parameter, however in a previous chapter it denied any relation between packages in Java.